# How can we use *ngFor for iteration in angular6 to show 3 images at a time in angular6

Tags: angular, html, css, angular-material, carousel

This code has added 3 images on one slides.How can I use *ngFor to get dynamic data??

```
 <carousel>
                <slide>
                  <img src="../../assets/wts1.png" alt="first slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;padding-right: 10px">
                  <img src="../../assets/wts1.png" alt="second slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;padding-right: 10px">
                  <img src="../../assets/wts1.png" alt="second slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;padding-right: 10px">
                </slide>
                <slide>
                    <img src="../../assets/wts2.png" alt="second slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
                        <img src="../../assets/wts2.png" alt="first slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
                        <img src="../../assets/wts2.png" alt="second slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
                      </slide>
                <slide>
                    <img src="../../assets/wts3.png" alt="third slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
                        <img src="../../assets/wts3.png" alt="first slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
                        <img src="../../assets/wts4.png" alt="second slide" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
                      </slide>
              </carousel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript

```
imageGroups = this.yourImageArray.reduce((p, c, i) => {
  if (i === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
    p.push([c]);
  } else {
    p[p.length - 1].push(c);
  }
  return p;
}, []);
```

HTML

```
<carousel>
  <slide *ngFor="let group of imageGroups">
    <img *ngFor="let image of group" [src]="'https://' + image.src" [alt]="image.description" style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;" />
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhhqry)

Comment: I would recommend using classes and not inline styles

Comment: Thanks you ..It's Working now

Comment: Hello BinaryPatrick,Can we move images left on click on next button in carousel?For example Now in one slot 3 images are displaying .If I click on next button another remaining 3 or less images are displayed.If I want to display 3 images in first slot and after click on next button need to show images are moving to left and next images neet to be displayed.Can we do this ??

Answer (score -1):

Angular does not provide a functionality to group elements directly in the template.
The cleanest way to achieve the result is use the [chunk function from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk) (or something similar) to create an array of arrays with the specified length and loop through the "outer" array.